# How to properly define regex as global variables in gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to define a regex expression as a global variable in `gitlab-ci.yml`.

the variable is:

```
variables:
  -SPEEDY_REGEX: '(chore|docs|feat|fix|refactor|style|test)\:( |\t)+\[SPEEDY\].*'
```

now I want to use it in if statements for getting specific builds to run:

```
build:
  rules:
    - if : '$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ $SPEEDY_REGEX'
      when: never
    - when: on_success
build:speedy:
  rules:
    - if : '$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ $SPEEDY_REGEX'
      when: on_success
    - when: never
```

This didn't want to work for a reason I ignore.

Comment: Have you tried / instead of " in the regex? Many languages use / to quote regular expressions. Maybe SPEEDY_REGEX=/(chore|docs|feat|fix|refactor|style|test)\:( |\t)+\[SPEEDY\].*/

Comment: @DaveH. yes but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, because of the way regex is parsed in `rules:` you won't be able to use variables as part of your regex.

Instead, for a DRY approach, you can consider other methods for re-using YAML sections, such as anchors, `extends` or `!reference` tags.

```yaml
.speedy_rules:
  rules:
    - if : '$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /(chore|docs|feat|fix|refactor|style|test)\:( |\t)+\[SPEEDY\].*/'
      when: never
    - when: on_success

build:
  rules: !reference [.speedy_rules, rules]
  # ...

example:
  rules:
    - if: '$SOMETHING == "another rule"'
    - !refernece [.speedy_rules, rules]

example2:
  extends: .speedy_rules
  # ...
```